Device Fingerprint on server-side
I want to generate a unique identifier for users (guests) on my website. I understand fingerprint.js uses browser APIs to generate a unique fingerprint that can be used as a session ID for a guest user. However, the confusing part for me is how to mimic its behavior at the server side.
As a reference, I have a page which is a server component which makes API calls and we want to generate the unique IDs before these API calls as this ID is necessary for these server calls.
What are the best practices to achieve these unique fingerprint IDs in server side frameworks?
I tried using FingerprintJS however the issue is that it is executed on the client side whereas, the API calls necessary for the server components to be rendered requires fingerprint.

The best (and mostly only) way to really fingerprint a user is client-side, no ways around it, as browsers tend to ommit most identifying information and a fingers print is mostly generated using browser features, which don't come along in headers. Since fingerprinting is on the edge of scumminess anyway, you will just have to deal with the fact that the user can fake it. They can also run a fake browser. All you know about the user is what they send you and what you can gather and send to yourselves. But consider a login instead of a fingerprint, tbh.

If(?) you need a session ID, then why don't you create a random one, as is usually done? Not sure what improvement using a device fingerprint would have in that scenario? (It would probably rather have disadvantages, because these fingerprints are not necessarily unique, https://github.com/fingerprintjs/fingerprintjs?tab=readme-ov-file#accuracy)

Firstly, It is not possible to generate this unique fingerprint on server side.
Now, a simple workaround is to add a client component and store the fingerprint in a cookie so that it is picked up automatically.
You can access this cookie in server component as follows.
import { cookies } from 'next/headers'

export default async function Page() {
  const cookieStore = await cookies()
  const theme = cookieStore.get('fingerprint')
  return '...'
}

